# How does C++ initialize inline variable via "constructor initialization"?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I'm working on a exercise that my professor gave to me in the last exams.

The text is as follow (its translated, original was in italian):

> Write a class template `SmartP<T>` of smart pointers of type `T` that redefine assignment, copy constructor and destructor of smart pointers. The template `SmartP<T>` must contain a minimal public interface (with less number of menbers) that allow compiling the following code, the execution will provoke the commented line

```
class C {
public:
    int* p;
    C(): p(new int(5)) {}
};

int main() {
    const int a = 1;
    const int *p = &a;
    SmartP<int> r;
    SmartP<int> s(&a);
    SmartP<int> t(s);
    cout << *s << " " << *t << " " << *p << endl; // 1 1 1
    cout << (s == t) << " " << !(s == p) << endl; // 0 1
    *s = 2;
    *t = 3;
    cout << *s << " " << *t << " " << *p << endl; // 2 3 1
    r = t;
    *r = 4;
    cout << *r << " " << *s << " " << *t << " " << *p << endl; // 4 2 3 1
    C c;
    SmartP<C> x(&c);
    SmartP<C> y(x);
    cout << (x == y) << endl; // 0
    cout << *(c.p) << endl; // 5
    *(c.p) = 6;
    cout << *(c.p) << endl; // 6
    SmartP<C> *q = new SmartP<C>(&c);
    delete q;
}
```

The solution provided by my professor is as follow:

```
template<class T>
class SmartP{
private:
    T* ptr;
public:
    SmartP(const SmartP& p) { p.ptr!=0 ? ptr(new T(*(p.ptr))) : ptr(nullptr); };
    SmartP(const T* t = 0) { t!=0 ? ptr(new T(*t)) : ptr(nullptr); };
    ~SmartP() { delete ptr;}
    T& operator*() const { return *ptr;}
    bool operator==(const SmartP& p) const { return ptr == p.ptr;}
    SmartP& operator=(const SmartP& p) {
       delete ptr;
       p.ptr!=0 ? ptr(new T(*(p.ptr))) : ptr(nullptr);
       return *this;
    }
};
```

But when i try this, i get an error on every "constructor initialization" that says:

> Called object type 'C*' is not a function or function pointer" (note that if i delete the C class i get the same error but instead on 'C*' there is 'int*').

So i was courious about this and i give to it some test:

```
    SmartP(const SmartP& p) : ptr(new T(*(p.ptr))) {}; //no error
    SmartP(const SmartP& p) { ptr(new T(*(p.ptr))); }; //error
    SmartP(const SmartP& p) { ptr = new T(*(p.ptr)); }; //no error
    SmartP(const SmartP& p) {
        if(p.ptr!=0){
            ptr(new T(*(p.ptr))); //error
        } else {
            ptr(nullptr);
        }
    };
```

So my question is How does C++ initialize inline variable via "constructor initialization"?

Why if I initialize my variable normally it works, but not with "constructor initialization"?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. Also please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question. There might be informational notes that gives further hints.

Comment: That is a weird smart pointer. Because it always creates new objects when copied or moved, instead of moving ownership, it will destroy the created object always when the originally owning smart pointer is destroyed, meaning that it does exactly the same thing as if the object was simply declared as automatic variable. It seems completely superfluous.

Comment: Also `class C` makes no sense. Even if that is only an example, there is no good reason for it to allocate memory with `new`, especially when it always leaks that memory, considering it doesn't call `delete` anywhere.

Comment: @walnut yes there are some typo in te solution operator=. it's totally wrong cause i copied a line for my tests an i forgot to change it back to the original one.

Comment: @ToldoDM I suggest you edit your question to actually show the code you were given and not some modification you did, so that we are not getting hung up about these irrelevant issues.

Comment: @walnut this was an exercise to do based on the given text thats on the first box: the goal was to adapt that code to work in that way, its not optimized and a lot of code is kinda no sense, but this is the way my professor finds out if you actually learn somthing about C++. Anyway thanks a lot for your opinion and help.

Comment: @ToldoDM The `operator=` that you are now showing does not have the issues I was mentioning anymore (besides the wrong assignment syntax that your question is about), but it is still not good, because it is not exception-safe. (But that one might be acceptable as simplification for the purpose of the course.) There are still some weird things in the code, though. Issues of my remaining comments aside, as mentioned by @t.niese it is not formatted well and then also the use of `0` instead of `nullptr` is (not wrong but) weird. If `nullptr` is used later, why not everywhere?

Comment: @walnut well its all about what we have done in class, my professor due to an injury has left a lot of topics yet to be addressed. One of this topic is exeption, that we will get on the next month. Anyway speaking on the 0-nullptr, one lesson he explain how the compiler work with these two. It's better to use nullptr, but he accept both.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing it out, I have already received an answer so now I don't think it makes sense for me to reformat the question. However, the next time I have doubts to ask, I will take it into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr(new T(*(p.ptr)));` Such member initialization is allowed only in a constructor outside its body, a.k.a. member initializer list. If you use this line in a constructor body, it's a call of a function with name `ptr` or `ptr.operator()`. The compiler says you exactly the same, `ptr` of type `C*` is not a function nor functional object.

Only two ways how to initialize `ptr` are possible, and all these ways are in your first and third lines, that you marked as no error.

More info: [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)